# Spring MVC: There was an error parsing the JSON document

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring-MVC for REST communication. This is the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/db")
public class RestController {

    @Inject
    private EmpRepositoryImpl empRepository;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/{tableName}.json", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public String getTableRecords(  @PathVariable String tableName){

        List<Map<String, Object>> resultList = empRepository.getAllEmpRecords(tableName);

        return resultList.toString();
    }

}
```

and the result I get in firefox is this:

```
There was an error parsing the JSON document. The document may not be well-formed.
expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3
[{nodeID=0, neo_eb_id=11, neo_eb_bossID=11, neo_eb_name='Smith'}, {nodeID=1, neo_eb_id=12, neo_eb_bossID=11, neo_eb_name='Johnson'}, {nodeID=2, neo_eb_id=13, neo_eb_bossID=11, neo_eb_name='Roberts'}, {nodeID=3, neo_eb_id=14, neo_eb_bossID=13, neo_eb_name='Doe'}]
```

1. **What seems to be the problem with this JSON format that spring generates?**
2. **How to display this result in JSON that can be displayed in eyecandy syntax highlighting with indentation and stuff as it takes place in other json I open with firefox?**

Comment: why you are using resultList.toString() method? why don't you just return a list from this method and let the jackson or which ever library you are using convert it? I would prefer just return resultList from your controller method.

Comment: Well I thought that spring will make json out of the `getTableRecords` if i declare `produces = "application/json"`.
I can't just return a List as it is. What do you mean return a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/db")
public class RestController {

    @Inject
    private EmpRepositoryImpl empRepository;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/{tableName}.json", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Map<String, Object>> getTableRecords(  @PathVariable String tableName){
        return empRepository.getAllEmpRecords(tableName);
    }
}
```

assuming you're using spring 3.2.x, spring will automatically register the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` that is capable of transforming the value returned by the handler method to valid JSON. This converter supports `application/json` and will be created and registered automatically by spring unless Jackson is not on the classpath (maybe you'll have to add Jackson to your classpath manually). As long as you don't have any advanced requirements, the default Jackson configuration by Spring is sufficient and works perfectly.

Additionally, by using this approach (@ResponseBody and returning the model itself, not a specific representation) you gain the ability of using different converters (e.g., for XML) ,based on e.g., the Accept header, without having to change your Controller. You'll only have to add additional converters to your Spring configuration.

And a very important benefit of this approach is .... you have testable code!

Comment: Thank you for this accurate answer and for elaboration on benefits. I accept this as solution.

Answer (score -1):

`{nodeID=0, neo_eb_id=11, neo_eb_bossID=11, neo_eb_name='Smith'}` is incorrect JSON syntax.  It should be `{nodeID:0, neo_eb_id:11, neo_eb_bossID:11, neo_eb_name:'Smith'}` (`:` instead of `=` to separate the field names and values).  An even better version would be `{ "nodeID"= 0, "neo_eb_id"= 11, "neo_eb_bossID"= 11, "neo_eb_name"= "Smith" }`.

Try validating your JSON at http://jsonlint.com for finding specific problems.